# Displaying Relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relationship

I wrote a CQL, and i am getting the result in the tabular format, now i want to show it graphically.

Here is the code in CQL:

```
match (tc:TeamCoaches)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Teams)
with t.TeamName as TeamNames, 
count(distinct tc.CoachName) as no_of_coach,
collect (tc.CoachName) as Coachnames
where no_of_coach>= 2
return  TeamNames, no_of_coach,Coachnames

Actual Results:

TeamNames               no_of_coach           Coachnames
A                            2                 [P,Q]
B                            3                 [X,Y,Z]
```

Expected Results: Should be in graphical form.
Example:

```
       (P)------------->(A)<---------------(Q)
            BELONGS_TO         BELONGS_TO


             BELONGS_TO        BELONGS_TO
       (X)------------->(B)<--------------->(Y)
                         ^
                         |
                         |BELONGS_TO
                         |
                        (Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `nodes` instead of their properties(here you are returning names) to show in the graph form.

You can modify your query to show in graph form as :

```
MATCH (tc:TeamCoaches)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Teams)
WITH t, count(distinct tc) as no_of_coach
WHERE no_of_coach>= 2
MATCH P=(tc:TeamCoaches)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(t)
RETURN  P
```